# What's the difference between class name & shortname in OrientDB?

Tags: java, graph, database, orientdb

What's the difference between class name & shortname in OrientDB?

Reference: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Alter-Class

Is there any difference in regard to performance or disk space usage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While shortname acts as an alias for a class (see [OrientDB Issue 901 - "...change shortName to alias"](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/901) in some contexts, it seems that shortname can't be used universally in reference to the class.  For example:

- `select from <shortname>` works as expected, selecting the records associated with the class for which shortname is an alias;
- `drop class <shortname>`, however, does not actually drop the corresponding class (just tried this with version 1.6.3).

Unfortunately, you'll probably have to do your own instrumentation to determine runtime performance and/or disk usage for your application.